# Pandas groupby count to have headers in same line

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'A':list('ababab'),
'B':list('aaabbb'),
'C':list('xyzklm'),
})
```

I am trying to groupby `A` and `B` and count. So, what I have tried is:

```
Option 1: 
    df.groupby(["A","B"]).agg('count')

Option 2: 
    df.groupby(["A","B"])["B"].agg('count')

Option 3:
    df.groupby(["A","B"], as_index=False).agg('count')
```

here are the outputs:

[image]

But, I want to have all header (A, B, C) in the same line as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't what's the purpose for doing this but one hack is to set `C` also as an `index`.

```
x= df.groupby(["A","B"]).agg('count').reset_index()
y = x.set_index(["A", "B", "C"])
```

---

**y:**

[image]

With Styling:

```
%%HTML
<style type="text/css">
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    border: 1px  black solid !important;
  color: black !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]